# How can i set to only our country and google bot can see my web site?

Tags: php, user-agent, googlebot, country, countries

I added to this code to index.php on opencart system.

```
if(!strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "googlebot"))
{
    if($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"] =! 'UK')
    { 
       echo "You can not see this page.";
       die();
    }
}
```

But i can see this page with proxy web sites from other countries. I want to only My Country IP and googlebot see this page.

Comment: `=!` are you sure about this?

Comment: don't be raciest, thanks

Comment: @Dagon dumb comment, the question might be about legal restrictions.

Comment: well considering how trivial it is to get around - the legal restrictions make no sense

Comment: @Dagon if cloudflare guarantees that this header is set properly, it would be enough from the webmasters point of view.

Comment: as the op points out any one with enough sense to use a proxy can defeat it - it is 100% impossible to stop someone viewing the site from a 'blocked' country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to  try:

```
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'googlebot') !== false OR $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"] == 'UK') {
    echo "GoogleBot and UK users will see this";
}else{
    die("DENIED");
}
```

Comment: `$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]` - only on CloudFlare

Comment: Yup, I had the same question at first and then I google it.

Comment: I tried a lot of this code but with cloudflare work it.
Thanks you so much Pedro Lobito and Dagon.

Comment: You're welcome!   If my answer helped you please consider accepting it. Tks!